# Optimised way to search all occurrences of text through web page in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, optimization, google-chrome-extension, full-text-search

I have a chrome extension which search though the webpage to look for given array of string. If string is present on web-page it got replaced  with a given block of HTML. So far i was looking the string only in `p` (paragraph) tags. But that doesn't give me all occurrences of string. (some are placed in `div` element in some websites, some has that text within `h6` tag).

So, i decided to iterate through all possible tags (p, h5, h2, h3,h6, h4, li, div) to look for element.  This is where the problem arises. It just works fine when i was looking into the `p` tags only and web-page is of small size (around 2000-3000 words). But freezes the browser overall if I do such heavy stuff with all tags.

Here is my code, and i am looking some good suggestions to optimize.

A brief of what i have done:

- So i was receiving the given string as object literal from chrome storage.
- Iterate the object for each word and extract the `p` elements from page.
- Looping through content of each p element to look for given word and replace it with something.
- Overall O(n^2) for `p` tag only.

```js
function isJson(item) {
  item = typeof item !== "string"
      ? JSON.stringify(item)
        : item;
  try {
      item = JSON.parse(item);
  } catch (e) {
      return false;
  }

  if (typeof item === "object" && item !== null) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function loop(elements, words) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var text = element.innerHTML;
    for (k in words) {
      var ol = document.createElement('ol'); 
          ol.setAttribute("style", "padding: 15px !important; padding-right: 0px !important; margin: 0 auto !important;");
      if(isJson(words[k])){
        defObj = JSON.parse(words[k]);
        // console.log(defObj);
        for (var j = defObj["data"].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
          var li = document.createElement('li');
          li.setAttribute("style", "padding: 5px 0; color:white !important; font-weight: normal !important; list-style: decimal !important; font-size: 12px !important;  border-bottom: 1px solid #11998e !important;  margin: 0px !important; ");
          if (defObj["data"][j]["definition"]) {
            li.innerText = (defObj["data"][j]["wordtype"] ? defObj["data"][j]["wordtype"] : defObj["data"][j]["partOfSpeech"]) + ";  "+ defObj["data"][j]["definition"];
          }else{
            li.innerText =  defObj["data"][j]["translatedText"];
          }
          ol.appendChild(li);
        } 
      }else{
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.setAttribute("style", "padding: 5px 0; color:white !important; font-weight: normal !important; list-style: decimal !important; font-size: 12px !important;  border-bottom: 1px solid #11998e !important; margin: 0px !important; ");
        li.innerText = words[k];
        ol.appendChild(li);
      }

      // Create a dummy outer div and append the ol into it to get the DOM OL as text. 
      var tmp = document.createElement("div");
      tmp.appendChild(ol);
      // console.log(tmp.innerHTML); 
      var regex = new RegExp('(\\b)'+k+'(\\b)', 'ig');
      text = text.replace(regex, '<span class="dict-highlight">&nbsp;'+k.toLowerCase()+'</span> <div class="dict-tooltip">  <span class="dict-tooltiptext">'+tmp.innerHTML+'</span>  <img class="annotate-img" src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/ZShyfCKFTKKmXouhbBQ2Zw.png"></div>'); 
    }

    if (element.innerHTML !== text) {
        element.innerHTML = text;
    }
  }
}

// Add attribute to check weather extension is installed or not
body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
body[0].setAttribute("data-dictozo-extension-installed", true);

chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(result) {

  if (result) {
    var elementsP = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    loop(elementsP, result);
    var elementsDIV = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    loop(elementsDIV, result);
    var elementsH5 = document.getElementsByTagName('h5');
    loop(elementsH6, result);
    var elementsH6 = document.getElementsByTagName('h6');
    loop(elementsH6, result);
    var elementsLI = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    loop(elementsLI, result);
  } 
});
```

While looking for single tag doesn't show any sign of slowdown but for all (p, h5, h2, h3, h6, h4, li, div) tags, it is definitely not a good idea. Please help.

Comment: 1) Use `ol.outerHTML` instead of creating `tmp`, 2) Create all regexps only one time before doing `loop` - for example use `Map` keyed on `k` with the regexp as the value, 3) Try to rework your algorithm so you don't need to create `ol` element, and instead do everything on a string, 4) Learn to use devtools performance panel to ensure you make meaningful progress, there are good official tutorials.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a query. Take a look at this page https://www.darjeeling-tourism.com/darj_000089.htm It has 695 div elements in total. According to above code, looping through these number of elements against a list of 100 words, make 695*100 = 69500 (max) operations, even such a low count freezes the webpage. I know JS runs on single thread, but don't you think  70000 operations are compared to nothing to those 3D rendering engines and image manipulation softwares or any other SASS software running heavily on client side. I expected it to run million of operations with no hussle. Isn't it?

Comment: DOM operations are super slow.